# Best way to update/rebuild a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, web-services

I'm working on a large webapp, which (among other things) has a table which is built from an existing set of data online. This data-set may change (though probably not frequently) so our general plan is to update/rebuild every 1-2 months. This will all be happening though Python with SQLAlchemy

With little experience in dealing with both webapps and large databases, what's the best way to do this? Building the database from scratch will take 5-6 hours, which, to be honest, is acceptable downtime (it's a scientific analysis server). Of course, another option is to create a second table in parallel, then drop the original table and rename the new one, but does this have consistency issues? Is there a way to "live update" a table, or is the risk of a crash here not worth it (i.e. if you crash leave the table in an inconsistent state relative to the real data)?

Clearly there's a trade off between simplicity, safety and lack of downtime, but I'm just interested in what my options are (to suss out those, "unknown unknowns").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend:

1. Back up the original table using mysqldump
2. Build the new table under a different name
3. Back up the new table using mysqldump
4. Shut down your application
5. Drop the old table
6. Rename the new table to the original table name
7. Restart your application

This should yield minimal down-time, just the time that it takes to drop the old table and rename the old one. The backups give you safety in case you screw something up.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

RENAME TABLE old_table TO tmp_table,
             new_table TO old_table;

Where new_table has created before. RENAME is atomic